# Is there a way to make Activities overview offer a link to the .desktop file for each entry?

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop, activities-overview

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and when I open the launcher ('*Activities*' overview) and search for an application I would sometimes like to edit the desktop file for one of the results.

Is there any way to go directly from the search to the appropriate desktop file or do I need to use command line tools to perform the search on the desktop files themselves instead.

I feel like the "show details" option should at the very least offer me the path to the desktop file but that only opens the software center, more often than not with no information on the application.

Answer (score 1):

The desktop files live in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`. A desktop file in the user's directory `~/.local/share/applications` takes precedence over a desktop file with the same name in the system-wide directory `/usr/share/applications`. If you want to modify a default desktop file, copy it from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications` and edit the copy.